# Given two 3D points and a length per point, find a shared endpoint closest to a given reference point

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I am reposting this because my original was really sloppy.

I am given the following information:
Two 3D points $P_1$ and $P_2$ that are starting points of two line segments in $3D$
The lengths $L_1$ and $L_2$ of the two line segments
A reference point $P_r$

With all this information, I need to find a shared **endpoint** of the two line segments with starting points $P_1$ and $P_2$ and with lengths $L_1$ and $L_2$ that is **closest** to $P_r$. The points can have any coordinates but cannot move from said coordinate, and their lengths can orient in any way. As for $P_r$, it cannot move, but it can have any length or direction and can be anywhere in space even within the intersection area.

**What I know:**
A sphere would perfectly represent all possible orientations of a line, given its starting point, so the information provided above can now become:
A Sphere $S_1$ with Center $C_1 = P_1$ and Radius $R_1 = L_1$
A Sphere $S_2$ with Center $C_2 = P_2$ and Radius $R_2 = L_2$

I followed this article, which seemed to be relevant up to Equation 9: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Sphere-SphereIntersection.html

I am stuck past this point. I know that the plane of intersection lies in the $y^2+z^2$ plane and that I'm supposed to project the reference point onto that plane to get my resulting endpoint.

What I have gathered from other tutorials is that the plane equation provides a vector $(0, 1, 1)$ because $x$ is not on the plane and the $1$'s are the invisible $1$ coefficients on $y$ and $z$.From there I just use the projection equation, but my answers never come out correct.

I have found this on stack overflow which is identical in terms of what they are asking me but I cannot get their sample input to equate to the sample output: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59599652/find-common-endpoint-of-two-3d-line-segments

Comment: One can find equation of plane by subtracting $((x-x_1)^2+(y-y_1)^2+(z-z_1)^2-L_1^2)-((x-x_2)^2+(y-y_2)^2+(z-z_2)^2-L_2^2)=0$. Then one can find intersection of line $(x_1+(x_2-x_1)t;y_1+(y_2-y_1)t,z_1+(z_2-z_1)t)$ with this plane. This will be the center of circle. Then one can find radius of circle using  Pythagoras theorem. Then one can find two orthogonal unit vectors lying in plane. Then one can parameterize circle as $(x_c,y_c,z_c)+a \cos u+b\sin u$. Then one can search for minimum of distance between point of circle and reference point using derivatives on $u$

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu so after expanding an cancelling all like terms I am left with the following:

-2hx + $h^2$ - 2ky + $k^2$ - 2lz + $l^2$ - $R^2$= [the same equation but for sphere 2] 

However, the resulting equation after subtracting the right from the left is sometimes not anywhere inside intersection let alone any of the spheres.

Answer (score 1):

First, find the distance between the two points $P_1$ and $P_2$

$d = \| P_1 P_2 \| $

Now form the triangle with sides $d, L_1, L_2$.  The intersection of the two spheres is a circle with radius $R$ where

$R = L_1 \sin(\phi) $

where $\phi = \cos^{-1} \left( \dfrac{L_1^2 + d^2 - L_2^2}{2 L_1 d } \right) $

If $V = \dfrac{P_2 - P_1}{d} $ , then the center of the circle is $C$ where

$ C = P_1 + L_1 \cos(\phi)  V $

Form the vector

$ U = P_r - C $

Project $P_r$ on the plane of the circle of intersection as follows

$ U' = C + U - (U \cdot V) V $

Form the vector

$W = U' - C $

Scale it, so that it has magnitude $R$

$W' = \dfrac{R}{\| W \| } W $

Now the desired point is

$ P_3 = C + W' $

Answer (score 0):

Algorithm of finding closest shared point in general case. This is realization of my short comment.

If distance $L=P_1P_2$ is greater than $L_1+L_2$ there are no shared point at all.

If $L=L_1+L_2$ there is only one shared point and it is the closest as unique. Shared point is located in the edge $P_1P_2$ at distance $L_1$ from $P_1$, this allows find it coordinates easily as $x_1+\frac{L_1}{L}(x_2-x_1)$ and so on.

Let $P_1(x_1;y_1;z_1)$, $P_2(x_2;y_2;z_2)$ and $L=\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2+(z_2-z_1)^2} < L_1+L_2$.

Then equation of sphere $C_1$ is
$$(x-x_1)^2+(y-y_1)^2+(z-z_1)^2=L_1^2$$

Equation of sphere $C_2$ is
$$(x-x_2)^2+(y-y_2)^2+(z-z_2)^2=l_2^2$$

Subtracting equation of $C_2$ from equation of $C_1$ one can get
$$(x-x_1)^2+(y-y_1)^2+(z-z_1)^2-(x-x_2)^2-(y-y_2)^2-(z-z_2)^2=L_1^2-L_2^2$$
Expansion and elimination gives
$$2x(x_2-x_1)+2y(y_2-y_1)+2z(z_2-z_1)+L_2^2-L_1^2=0$$
This is equation of plane $\alpha$ containing circle $C$ of intersection of $C_1$ and $C_2$.

Center of circle $C$ is located in line $P_1P_2$ and is located in the plane. $\alpha$. Let this center has coordinates $(x_3,y_3,z_3)$ such that $$x_3=x_1+(x_2-x_1)t,y_3=y_1+(y_2-y_1)t,z_3=z_1+(z_2-z_1)t$$

Then $$2x_3(x_2-x_1)+2y_3(y_2-y_1)+2z_3(z_2-z_1)+L_2^2-L_1^2=0$$
$$2((x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2+(z_2-z_1)^2)t=\\L_1^2-L_2^2-2x_1(x_2-x_1)-2y_1(y_2-y_1)-2z_1(z_2-z_1)$$
$$t=\frac{L_1^2-L_2^2-2x_1(x_2-x_1)-2y_1(y_2-y_1)-2z_1(z_2-z_1)}{2((x_1-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2+(z_2-z_1)^2)}$$

After calculation of $t$ we also know $x_3,y_3,z_3$.

Distance between center of circle and point $P_1$ is equal
$|t|L$. Then radius of circle is $R=\sqrt{L_1^2-t^2L^2}$.

Vector $\vec{P_1P_2}=(x_2-x_1;y_2-y_1;z_2-z_1)$ is normal to the plane. There are two possible options $\vec{P_1P_2}\parallel Ox$ or $\vec{P_1P_2}\nparallel Ox$. In first case we can take $\vec{a}=(0;R;0)$, $\vec{b}=(0;0;R)$. In second case we can take $\vec{a_1}=(1;0;0)\times\vec{P_1P_2}$, $\vec{b_1}=\vec{a_1}\times\vec{P_1P_2}$, $\vec{a}=R\frac{\vec{a_1}}{\sqrt{\vec{a_1}\cdot\vec{a_1}}}$, $\vec{b}=R\frac{\vec{b_1}}{\sqrt{\vec{b_1}\cdot\vec{b_1}}}$. In both cases $\vec{a}\perp \vec{P_1P_2}$, $\vec{b}\perp \vec{P_1P_2}$, $\vec{a}\perp\vec{b}$, $|\vec{a}|=|\vec{b}|=R$.

Then every point of circle $C$ is given by
$$x=x_3+a_x\cos u+b_x\sin u,y=y_3+a_y\cos u+b_y\sin u,z=z_3+a_z\cos u+b_z\sin u$$
Then square of distance from point of circle to point $P_r=(x_r;y_r;z_r)$ is equal
$$L_r^2=(x_3-x_r+a_x\cos u+b_x\sin u)^2+(y_3-y_r+a_y\cos u+b_y\sin u)^2+(z_3-z_r+a_z\cos u+b_z\sin u)^2$$
$$L_r^2=(x_3-x_r)^2+(y_3-y_r)^2+(z_3-z_r)^2+(a_x^2+a_y^2+a_z^2)\cos^2 u+\\(b_x^2+b_y^2+b_z^2)\sin^2 u+2(a_x b_x+a_y b_y+a_z b_z) \cos u \sin u+\\
2((x_3-x_r)a_x+(y_3-y_r)a_y+(z_3-z_r)a_z)\cos u+\\
2((x_3-x_r)b_x+(y_3-y_r)b_y+(z_3-z_r)b_z)\sin u$$

$|\vec{a}|=|\vec{b}|=R$, $\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}=0$, then
$$L_r^2=(x_3-x_r)^2+(y_3-y_r)^2+(z_3-z_r)^2+R^2+\\
2((x_3-x_r)a_x+(y_3-y_r)a_y+(z_3-z_r)a_z)\cos u+\\
2((x_3-x_r)b_x+(y_3-y_r)b_y+(z_3-z_r)b_z)\sin u$$

Let $A=2((x_3-x_r)a_x+(y_3-y_r)a_y+(z_3-z_r)a_z)$, $B=2((x_3-x_r)b_x+(y_3-y_r)b_y+(z_3-z_r)b_z)$, then
$$L_r^2=(x_3-x_r)^2+(y_3-y_r)^2+(z_3-z_r)^2+R^2+A\cos u+B\sin u$$

Let $X=A\cos u+B\sin u$, then
$$X^2=A^2\cos^2u+B^2\sin^2u+2AB\sin u \cos u=\\
A^2+B^2-(A^2\sin^2u+B^2\cos^2u-2AB\sin u \cos u)=\\
A^2+B^2-(A\sin u-B\cos u)^2 \leq A^2+B^2$$
Then $X\geq-\sqrt{A^2+B^2}$. Consider $u_1$ such that $$\cos u_1=-\frac{A}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}},\sin u_1=-\frac{B}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}$$
Then at $u=u_1$:
$$X=A\cos u_1+B\sin u_1=-\frac{A^2+B^2}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}=-\sqrt{A^2+B^2}$$
$u=u_1$ makes $X$ minimal then $L_r^2=(x_3-x_r)^2+(y_3-y_r)^2+(z_3-z_r)^2+R^2$ is also minimal.

Then closest shared point is point given by
$$x=x_3+a_x\cos u_1+b_x\sin u_1,y=y_3+a_y\cos u_1+b_y\sin u_1,z=z_3+a_z\cos u_1+b_z\sin u_1$$